# Join attributes by location in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I wonder if there is a better way to join attributes based on location.

I have a vector layer with polygons representing lines.
Layer A is the layer where I want to take the correct attributes and Layer B is the layer with the merged/dissolved polygons.

They're split into multi parts and I merged/dissolved them based on 'type' attribute (see image tables).

After merging/dissolving the polygons I want to re-assign the attributes back, based on the location.
I've tried the tool join attributes by location selecting 'contains' and 'one to one' join. The result displayed here is correct but with other features it looks like that it's taking the attributes of the adjacent polygon (which has different type attribute) instead of the
the polygon that falls in the same area and same attribute type.
So I have to check them manually which is a lot of time consuming if you have hundreds of features.

[image: Layer A][image: Layer B][image: attributes]

I have also tried using PostGIS, which I'm new, using the following spatial query:

SELECT table_A
FROM
table_A,
table_B
WHERE
st_contains(table_B.geom, table_A.geom);

Using this I get only a few features joined. What am I missing here?

Is there any other way to do this without spending too much time checking the features manually? Using python inside or outside QGIS or Arcmap?

Comment: For better visualisation, could you please label your polygons in order to show, based on which attribute you dissolve, as well as how you want attributes to be distributed afterwards.

Comment: If you dissolve (merge) the polygons: how should attributes be matched back? Beforde you start, each segment has individual attributes. From which of these should the merged polygons get the attribute value? Please provide more informaiton.

Comment: I've added more information. Does that help? @babel

Comment: In Join attributes by location, have you tried the *Take attributes of the feature with largest overlap only* Join type?

Comment: You could use the Point on Surface tool with the Create point on surface for each part checked, and then do a spatial join to the points.

Comment: I still don't understand why you have to re-join attributes. I tried to do exactely what can be seen on your screenshot, with the same fieldnames and attribute values. For dissolving, I selected `aggregate` (`Menu Processing / Tollbox`). For `group by expression` select a combination of type and streetname (that's what you want, according to your screenshot). Be sure to set an adequate `Aggregate Function` for each field - see screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeUL3.png. When I run the tool, I get the same output as the one you want (layer B), see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbazJ.png

Comment: Thanks for your answer @babel. That could be a good solution but the problem is that I don't want to aggregate/concatenate the attributes, only the shapes of the polygons based on the attribute 'type' and 'sets'. Before the re-join of the attributes, I had to buffer all the polygons, dissolve them, remove the buffer and convert multipart to singlepart. Some features have a small gap between them. They're not continuous as you see on the image. The result layer have all the features with the same attribute and this is when I have to put the attributes back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @johns.That seems a good suggestion and easy to join the attributes. I'll try it later.

Comment: Thanks @GabrielC. I'm using QGIS version 3.10 but I don't have this option in Join type. Thanks for the suggestion.